# JAVA - where should i put JUNG in my directory? im programming only in notepad

Tags: java, directory, package, jung

I downloaded the JUNG package but i don't know where should i put in my directory.

Comment: since you're programming in notepad, you can put it everywhere, just be sure that in the compiling command (javac) you use you set the -classpath option to the directory containing the jars.

Comment: Why. Why are you using Notepad. Especially with Java. At least use a decent editor.

Comment: btw switch editor, if you don't want an IDE like eclipse there are toons of more suitable editors, I actually use vim for trivial coding, but notepad++, SCITE, textpad are way better than plain vanilla notepad...

Comment: @BigMike THANK YOU SO MUCH SIR. ok i'll switch editor. :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming when you say you've downloaded the package you mean you've downloaded the libs.

You need to reference them in your build path.  This is defined in the .classpath file if you are using Eclipse.

Edit :

If you aren't using an IDE, use this...

```
javac -classpath external.jar myClass.java
```

Comment: yes i've downloaded the libs.
can you tell me what to do?

Comment: What IDE are you using?  Eclipse?

Comment: @david99world: He isn't. He's using Notepad. Windows Notepad.

Comment: no. i use only notepad when i'm coding my program. and i use the cmd to compile and run

Answer (score 1):

You really should try using Maven or similar tool. If you're against it, just put it in a "lib" folder and reference it in your .classpath

Comment: I would not recommend Maven to anyone who had to ask this question.